# NullReferenceException raises in MonoGame.Framework.DLL

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone-8, nullreferenceexception, monogame

I'm developing a little game for Windows Phone 8 with MonoGame. Lately my game started to crash at random moments with NullReference exception. Visual Studio points out spriteBatch.End() method but it happens somewhere inside MonoGame libraries.

Game starts with a splash screen then a start screen, there is a short story appears and then gameplay starts. Exception only occurs on gameplay but it happens on random moments. Sometimes its 2 seconds in gameplay, sometimes in 2 minutes. Sometimes it happens on first touch action, sometimes I don't touch at all and exception still occurs.

I had a touch problem about some specific zone of the screen, I had to delete StackFrame from GamePage.xaml to solve it, tried to add it back with copying from another GamePage.xaml. Also I'm using spriteBatch.Begin() method with 2 argumented override to get rid of premultiplied alpha. There is nothing else I changed that I can think of but I can't post any code atm the moment because of my supervisor. I can convince him if its neccessary.

---

EDIT: There are different game screens on my project and this exception only occurs on "level", "credits" etc works fine. I commented all Update method, exception happens on Draw even when I try to draw a simple background.

```
Game1.cs

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
    ScreenManager.Instance.Draw(spriteBatch);

    spriteBatch.End();        
}  


ScreenManager.cs(Singleton class)

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    if (!this.Paused) currentScreen.Draw(spriteBatch);
    else PauseMenu.Draw(spriteBatch); 
}


Level.cs(currentScreen is a Level everytime this happens)

public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    base.Draw(spriteBatch);
    if (!completed)
    {
        //Commented bla bla that draws everything else
    }
}


GameScreen.cs(Base class of Level)

public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(image, new Vector2(480, 0), null, this.Color,
        (float)(Math.PI / 2), new Vector2(0, 0), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
}
```

Level data is read on an XML file line by line with a XmlManager class, parseXml method creates a level and assign-load its properties according to Xml file, returns that level.

```
ScreenManager.Instance.currentScreen =
    ScreenManager.Instance.manager.ParseXml(this.Content, "Level" +
        ++ScreenManager.Instance.CurrentLevelId + ".xml");
```

That is how Levels initalized.

---

EDIT2:This only happens when I try to draw a texture, I can draw strings just fine.

Comment: Hi Mert and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid that this question is currently too unclear. Ideally for a question like this you should have a simple, self-contained example that exhibits the behaviour you have seen - otherwise it is unlikely another user will have hit the exact same issue you have and be in a position to help.

Comment: NullReference is probably the most common type of exception. It's not going to be easy to figure out without using your debugger. Given the nature of your problem it could be a threading race condition, maybe. You may need to build MonoGame from source and reference the project that way so you can see the exact line that throws the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, 
Paul Annetts, the problem is issue is unclear for me too, it is randomly chrashing not after an exact time or an exact behavior. 
craftworkgames, I know it is the most common exception and I spent some time on debugger to see anything null but I think I'm gonna spend some more to see if I can catch something.